# Adding a value from one table to another table where the IDs match

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a club table with a ClubId. This table has a field with the badge reference string. (I´ll acces the Picture itself through wwwroot). I now have a table with results. This results table has a hometeamId a hometeambadge field thats still empty and a awayteamId and a awayteambadge field thats also empty. I now want to write a methode where I add the badge string from the club table into the results table where the ClubId is equal to the hometeamId and the awayteamId.

How do I do this in a query in ASP.Net Core?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider having a sight to EntityFramework where it's easy to retrieve update and delete data from any common data store...

There you'll do things like

```
      int teamId=123; 
      var homeTeam= context.Find(teamId); 
      homeTeam.Badge=$"badge-{teamId}.png";
```

Then in your view you'll be able to reference the badge from within wwwroot folder